# Why does the Type class have a method called IsPrimitive() if the C# spec refers to them as simple types?

Tags: c#, naming, primitive-types, language-specifications, simpletype

Looking at the C# 6.0 Draft specification I saw nothing about primitive types; I only saw data about [Simple types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#simple-types). That said, the Type class has an [IsPrimitive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isprimitive?view=netcore-2.2) method.

Should IsPrimitve really be IsSimple?

Comment: Are those two lists **exactly** the same? _Hint - they aren't._

Comment: No. "Simple type" is a C# concept, "primitive type" is a CLR concept. `decimal` is an example of a type C# considers simple, but is not a primitive type.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Shouldn't you add this as an answer instead? :)

Comment: @mjwills They are not. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I see, I suppose that makes sense. Do you have any good references to CLR naming conventions?

Comment: I take it back, the CLR does not *directly* define primitive types as such. [ECMA-335](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) is the standard covering the CLR (or rather the CLI) and it only defines, in I.8.2.2., what it considers "built-in types". When filtered to value types, this is *almost* the same list as `Type.IsPrimitive` uses, save for `System.TypedReference`, which is a built-in value type but not considered "primitive". This type is not usually surfaced in managed languages, though.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I think your point still stands: the platform != the language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# "simple types" are (alphabetically) `bool`, `byte`, `char`, `decimal`, `double`, `float`, `int`, `long`, `sbyte`, `short`, `uint`, `ulong` and`ushort` . These are a set of struct types that C# has chosen to give special status, with special provisions other types don't get (as detailed in the standard), such as the ability to use them as constants.

`Type.IsPrimitive` is a different beast; it returns `true` for a limited set of value types (which C# formally calls "struct types", but very commonly called "value types" by C# developers anyway) that the runtime considers special in some way. These types are `Boolean`, `Byte`, `Char`, `Double`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `IntPtr`, `SByte`, `Single`, `UInt16`, `UInt32`, `UInt64` and `UIntPtr` (all living in `System`). These types all have in common that they are directly supported by the runtime as built-in types, so they have operations that are directly implemented by the JIT compiler rather than as compiled IL. (There is one more value type that meets these criteria which is not on this list of types, for some reason: `TypedReference`. This is rarely used in managed languages and detailing its purpose and use is something for another answer.)

The most striking difference between these lists is that C#'s simple type `decimal` is not a primitive type. This has some consequences: C# allows `decimal` constants, but the runtime does not -- they are really compiled as `static readonly` fields with some attribute magic, as [detailed by Jon Skeet here](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/22/when-is-a-constant-not-a-constant-when-its-a-decimal/). The designers of C# considered `decimal` important enough to label it a simple type, but it's not a built-in type, so the compiler has to make up for the difference.

The other important difference is that `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr` are built-in types, but C# does not consider them "simple", presumably since you're not really supposed to make much use of them in managed code outside interop scenarios, and also because they have restrictions that would not be shared by other simple types (you cannot declare `IntPtr` constants, not even on the IL level, because the actual size differs by platform).

So the short answer is: no, `Type.IsPrimitive` should not be named `Type.IsSimple`, although "primitive type" does not really have a single definition that I can see, beyond the raw listing of the types. "Built-in value type" does have a definition, which is almost but not entirely the same as what `Type.IsPrimitive` calls "primitive".